# Deriving $(\partial{H}/\partial{G})_{S}$

Tags: thermodynamics

Deriving $(\partial{H}/\partial{G})_{S}$.

I have a problem with deriving such relation.

For isentropic condition,

$dH = TdS + VdP = VdP$,

$dG = -SdT + VdP$.

$dS = (\partial{S}/\partial{T})_{P}dT + (\partial{S}/\partial{P})_{T}dP = 0$,

$(\partial{S}/\partial{T})_{P} = C_{P}/T$,

and by Maxwell realtions,

$(\partial{S}/\partial{P})_{T} = -(\partial{V}/\partial{T})_{P}$,

eventually,

$\frac{C_{P}}{T}dT -(\partial{V}/\partial{T})_{P}dP = 0$,

$dT = \frac{T}{C_{P}}\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{P}dP$.

Reaplcing $dT$ for the equation of $dG$.

So $dG$ and $dH$ are nicely described as a function of $P$ like below in this isentropic situation.

$dG = -S\frac{T}{C_{P}}\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{P}dP + VdP$

$dH = VdP$

What is the next move?

Comment: The next move is to do with dH the exact same thing you did with dG;  express dH as a function of dT and dP, and then substitute for  dT as a function of dP at constant S.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out.

So following my question,

$\left(\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{P}}\right)_{S} = V-S\frac{T}{C_{P}}\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{P}$,

$\left(\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P}}\right)_{S} = V$.

Because $\left(\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P}}\right)_{S}\left(\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{G}}\right)_{S} = \left(\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{G}}\right)_{S}$

dividing them,

$\left(\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{G}}\right)_{S} = V/\left[V-S\frac{T}{C_{P}}\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{P} \right]$

Am I correct?